# SQL exception while compiling no such table exist

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I want to get a some IQ level corresponding to some score achieved by the user. I have my database in assets folder. The database is succesfull created and opened.But it shows NO SUCH TABLE ERROR while i am 100% sure that table exist in my score.db file.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

String DB_PATH = null;
private static String DB_NAME = "score";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 10);
    this.myContext = context;
    this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + "com.example.madhav.loginandreg" + "/" + "databases/";
    Log.e("Path 1", DB_PATH);
}


public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion)
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
}

public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {
    return myDataBase.query(table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

}

public String getiqscore(int rawscore,String condition,String age,String what){
    String query="Select  "+what +" from " +age+ " where " +condition+"="+rawscore+";";
    String data=null;
    myDataBase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=myDataBase.rawQuery(query,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(what)) != null)
        data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(what));

    cursor.close();
    myDataBase.close();
    return data;
}
```

}

Java file for the above specified code:-

```
public class information extends AppCompatActivity {
RadioGroup[] rp= new RadioGroup[11] ;
int score=0;
DatabaseHelper db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_information);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
          db=new DatabaseHelper(information.this);

    try {
        db.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        db.openDataBase();
    } catch (Exception sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }

    rp[0]=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q1);
    rp[0]=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q1);
    rp[1]=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q2);
    rp[2]=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q3);
    rp[3]=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q4);
    rp[4]=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q5);
    rp[5]=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q6);
    rp[6]=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q7);
    rp[7]=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q8);
    rp[8]=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q9);
    rp[9]=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q10);
    rp[10]=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.q11);

}
public void submit(View view){
    for(int i=0 ; i<11 ; i++){
    String  id= String.valueOf(rp[i].getCheckedRadioButtonId());
       int idi;
        try{
            idi=rp[i].getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton r=(RadioButton) findViewById(idi);
            String a= (String) r.getText();
            if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("1           ")){
                score++;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(score),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    int a=Integer.valueOf(score);
    String iq= db.getiqscore(a,"VinfoRs","age10","VinfoTq");
    Toast.makeText(this,iq,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   // Intent intent=new Intent(this,activity3.class);
    //startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

```
enter code here java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                                                                           Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: age10 (code 1): , while compiling: Select  VinfoTq from  age10 where VinfoRs=11;
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
                                                                              at com.example.madhav.loginandreg.DatabaseHelper.getiqscore(DatabaseHelper.java:111)
                                                                              at com.example.madhav.loginandreg.information.submit(information.java:80)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: private static String DB_NAME = "score"; 
this should be .db
private static String DB_NAME = "score.db ";

Comment: Please show add the complete stacktrace and the complete exception message to your Question.

Comment: FWIW - based on the code you have shown us, the most likely explanation is that you don't have a table called "age10" in the database that you have opened.  Maybe you created the wrong table, or "age10" is not the table name you intended to use, or ... you opened the wrong database file (i.e. not the one where you created that table)

Comment: Added the the complete exception message!

Comment: i have checked the table name in my db browser.There exist the table with exact same name and attributes

Comment: Well, maybe you are using a different DB file to the on that you examined with the browser.  Either way, the database library will not be lying to you.

Comment: @StephenC i have checked that i am using the same file as opened in my DB browser. I think there is some logical error i have done maybe while creating or opening or copying the database.

Comment: That is possible.  Remember, the library won't lie.  If it can't find that table with that name, then it isn't in the database it is looking at.

Comment: @stephenC ya,can you find that logical error please?

Answer (score 0):

Remove static value in byte and uset actual value from InputStream.

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[myInput.available()];
        myInput.read(buffer);
        myOutput.write(buffer);
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }
```

Comment: Tried that but didn't work. Actually the exception occurs at when cursor executes the raw query.

Comment: is there availabel age10 table? what's your table name?

Comment: yes, the table name is age10 only. There is no issue of name mismatch.

Comment: There is surely some logical error. i have checked that i am using the same file and same table  as opened in my DB browser. I think there is some logical error i have done maybe while creating or opening or copying the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your database creation logic looks strange.  I can't figure out why your `DatabaseHelper` is extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`.  The only place where you used any of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` functionality is when you call `this.getReadableDatabase()`.  But even that seems to be wrong.  You don't make use of the `SQLiteDatabase` that it returns, and (!!) you don't close it.

Instead you appear to copy a your template database file over the top of the readonly database that you just created, and then open it.  I don't know what that will do, but it could be that you actually end up returning an `SQLiteDatabase` that refers to your readonly database ... which is presumably empty.

Either way, that logic seems broken.  (And I'm not an Android programmer ...)

Comment: Please tell me what to do?? what changes?

Comment: Erm ... sorry, but StackOverflow is not a "fix my bugs" service.